# Can my US-born adult daughter apply for a British passport?

Tags: united-kingdom, passport

I was born in British India in 1940 to an Indian father and British mother. Although my mother was British born, she nevertheless applied for me to become a British citizen by naturalization when I was 9 years old. I was living in England with my British grandparents and attending a boarding school. I lived in the UK from 1946 to 1962.

I moved to the US in 1962, married an American woman, and had a daughter born there in 1976. I did not know that that time that I could have registered my daughter's birth at a British consulate. In spite of not registering my daughter, can she still apply for a British passport as an adult? I went to the GOV.UK sites and could not figure out her eligibility for one. If she can apply, what does she have to do to get one?

Comment: Do you know what provision you were naturalized under?

Answer (score 1):

If you were really British citizen "by naturalization", then you are a British citizen otherwise than by descent, which means that (since you are the father and your daughter was born in wedlock) your child born abroad was automatically British citizen at birth (technically, at the time it was called Citizen of the United Kingdom and Colonnies (CUKC) with right of abode in the UK, which in 1983 became British citizen). There was no need to "register" your daughter -- she would have been a British citizen automatically. In this case, she can just apply for a British passport (with the requisite proof of your British citizenship otherwise than by descent and your relationship to her).